# efficient string char elimination in python

Tags: python, string, performance

I have a python for loop over a string, that have to decide char-by-char if the current char should stay or be removed.

Let's say I have a function `fun(character,state)` which receives a char, and some state parameter, and returns `True` if the char should be kept, and a new `state`. for example:

```
def fun(c,state):
    if state%5==0:
        return False, state+1
    else:
        return True, state+2
```

I have two ideas how to iterate (sequentially) over the string with this function, but I can't decide between them (or others) in terms of **runtime complexity** and **space usage** tradeoff:

### Option 1:

```
def option1(string):
    state = 0
    i =0
    while i<len(string):
        answer, state = fun(string[i],state)
        if not answer:
             string = string[:i]+string[i+1:]
        else:
            i+=1
    return string
```

### Option 2:

```
def option2(string):
    result  = ''
    state = 0
    for c in string:
        answer, state = fun(c,state)
        if answer:
             result+=c
   return result
```

Does anyone has a better approach/ solution?

---

**edit:** some timing results:

on a long string ( 67976 chars) the results are:

- option1 - 205 ms
- option2 - 46 ms

looks like eliminating the i'th char with `string[:i]+string[i+1:]` is not a good idea.

Comment: You can just measure the performance and see what happens. Your best bet in making this faster (if it matters) is avoiding the function call per character altogether.

Comment: I'm looking for a theoretical point of view, since just timing won't find a better approach.

Comment: I'm not sure what the theoretical differences here are. You have to iterate over the entire string and apply your condition. The rest are implementation details that are very much a matter of measurement. They'll also tend to dominate the running time (i.e. how many function calls you make, how many new strings you instantiate and instantly turn to garbage, etc).

Comment: Your option 1 may be slow because you are calculating `len(string)` every loop.

Comment: Now that you're measuring things, try taking out the function call as an experiment - you'll see it completely dominates the time taken, making your option2 (and the one in the `join` answer below) nearly two times faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String concatenation with `+=` is not recommended. 
Better use a list and join it.

```
def option2(string):
    result  = []
    state = 0
    for c in string:
        answer, state = fun(c, state)
        if answer:
             result.append(c)
   return ''.join(result)
```

This a good [explanation](http://www.bernardi.cloud/2012/11/06/python-string-concatenation-vs-list-join/) why.
While `+=` is optimized in CPython (for certain cases?), it can be really slow in other implementations such as  PyPy, for example.

Comment: indeed, the time elapsed is ``38 ms`` - the best by now

Answer (score 1):

In CPython, a good performance rule of thumb is 'avoid function calls in tight loops'. The overhead tends to take a significant amount of time compared to simple iterative computations. In your case, a 'brute force' approach is to simply inline the logic in the loop that traverses your string:

```
def option4(strng):
    result  = []
    state = 0
    for c in strng:
        if state % 5 == 0:
            state += 1
        else:
            result.append(c)
            state += 2
    return ''.join(result)
```

This may feel a little clunky, a more 'pythonic' approach might be to use a python generator that takes an iterable and initial state as input and yields the matching members.

```
def filtergen(iter, initstate):
    state = initstate
    for c in iter:
        if state % 5 == 0:
            state += 1
        else:
            state += 2
            yield c

def option5(strng):
    return ''.join(filtergen(strng, 0))
```

This reduces call overhead - you only need as many calls as matching elements and as a side benefit, frees the caller from the need to keep track of state. Additionally, you no longer need the intermediate list. The filter remains generic - it works on any kind of iterable, rather than just strings.

Putting all of these together and measuring performance:

```
s = 'T0kzcZ0x8VQY8ulgFKU8D1MlIUULRsVsNZMnXbjliUEES6sEIVUzpjxlHLG59z' * 1200

def fun(c, state):
    if state % 5 == 0:
        return False, state + 1
    else:
        return True, state + 2

def option3(strng):
    result  = []
    state = 0
    for c in strng:
        answer, state = fun(c, state)
        if answer:
             result.append(c)
    return ''.join(result)

def option4(strng):
    result  = []
    state = 0
    for c in strng:
        if state % 5 == 0:
            state += 1
        else:
            result.append(c)
            state += 2
    return ''.join(result)

def filtergen(iter, initstate):
    state = initstate
    for c in iter:
        if state % 5 == 0:
            state += 1
        else:
            state += 2
            yield c

def option5(strng):
    return ''.join(filtergen(strng, 0))

import timeit
print("string length is " + str(len(s)))
print(timeit.timeit('option3(s)', globals=globals(), number=100))
print(timeit.timeit('option4(s)', globals=globals(), number=100))
print(timeit.timeit('option5(s)', globals=globals(), number=100))

print(option3(s) == option(4) == option5(s))
```

On my dinky laptop, the output looks like this (times are in seconds):

```
pvg /tmp ➤  python3 s.py
string length is 74400
2.488818967998668
1.3291878789968905
1.268602224998176
True
```

The 'inline logic' and generator both easily outperform the naive call-per-element approach.